# Synchronized blocks with static attribute vs shared attributes vs synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I tested three versions of the same problem, expecting all to provide perfect synchronization:

**1) Using a static variable as the lock:**

```
public class SynchronizedIncrement implements Runnable {
    private static int x = 0;
    private Object o = new Object();

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
            synchronized(o) {
                ++x;
            }
    }
}
```

**2) Using the same object as lock, passed as an argument in the constructor:**

```
public class SynchronizedIncrement implements Runnable {
    private static int x = 0;
    private Object o = null;

    public SynchronizedIncrement(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
                synchronized(o) {
                    ++x;
                }
    }
}
```

**3) Declaring `run()` as a `synchronized` method:**

```
public synchronized void run() {
    for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
        ++x;
}
```

I am using a fixed thread pool of 100 threads for the tests:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    //Object obj = new Object(); // used as argument for the second version
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
        es.submit(new Thread(new SynchronizedIncrement()));
    es.shutdown();
    while (!es.isTerminated());
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Outputs for version 1, 2 and 3:

```
560126
1000000
976082
```

Only the second one returns the expected result. Why do the other two fail?

Comment: The lock in the first example is *not* a static variable.

Comment: also, no need for `new Thread`. Just submit the Runnables you already have directly.

Comment: @Thilo you're right, I forgot to declare it `static`, how dumb. Also thanks for poiting out no need to wrapping the `Runnable` object in a `Thread`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The first code will use reference o as a object monitor for synchronization. Object o is a different object for each instance of SynchronizedIncrement so each thread will lock its own monitor, allowing them all to run in parallel thus incrementing the static variable x inconsistently.
2. The second implementation will use the object passed as argument to the constructor to lock the thread. You have a single reference (obj) that you're passing to all threads in which case all synchronization will be done on the same object thus incrementing the static variable x consistently.
3. The last piece of code will synchronize on "this" (itself) so it behaves identically to the first version.

A usual design, is to keep the data accessed by multiple thread encapsulated in a different class and synchronize the interface methods to that class.

Here, a tradeoff would be to have a method incX() and declare that:

```
static synchronized void incX(){
    x++;
}
```

In this case, your run methods don't need to be synchronized.

Comment: +1. This is the proper explanation. In real life, I'd use AtomicInteger. No need to implement synchronization yourself.

Comment: That usual design you mention would be a monitor, right?

Comment: @dabadaba A monitor isn't a design :) I mean the proper way to right a multi-threaded application is to have the resources that are commonly used by multiple threads declared in separate class and encapsulated such as you only provide an set of interface methods to access the data. These methods can handle synchronization, either by using the "synchronized" keyword, or by using thread safe data structures from java.util.concurrent like the AtomicInteger that Thilo noted.

Comment: @rhobincu that's the exact definition of what I've always understood a monitor is.

Comment: @dabadaba Ah, you mean the design patter "Monitor object", yes, sounds like it. The Java opcodes that lock and unlock a semaphore are called monitorenter and monitorexit, so I was assuming that by monitor you were referring to the actual Java object used for synchronization (like o and obj in your code).

Comment: @rhobincu No, I didn't refer to the object used as lock, by monitor I mean what you just described: a class that encapsulates the critical resources and provide synchronization in all its methods so these resources are treated consistently.

Answer (score 2):

In your first and third example all threads use another object for synchronizing.

First example:

```
public class SynchronizedIncrement implements Runnable {
    private static int x = 0;
    private Object o = new Object(); // Each new SynchronizedIncrement will create its own new Object.

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
            synchronized(o) { // All threads can still interleave and access 'x'.
                ++x;
            }
    }
}
```

Third example:

```
public synchronized void run() { // Now the threads synchronize again on its own object each: the thread itself!
    for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
        ++x;
}
```

Only the second example is correctly synchronized because all threads use the *same* object for synchronizing.

Answer (score 0):

Only the second approach uses the same synchronization object in all threads. Therefore only the second one delivers the expected results.

In your first approach each thread produces its own `new Object()`. You have to use one central Object - `SynchronizedIncrement.class` or the `static int x` for example (possibly refactored to `Integer` to get an object instead of primitive).

The result of your third approach is still somewhat unclear to me. This realy may be caused by printing the result before all threads have terminated.